# setOnClickListener in Recycler View Crashes

Tags: android

I have recently started implementing `RecyclerView`. I have implemented horizontal recyclerview with image and imagebutton. I want to know position of which image or imagebutton is clicked. I could able to see six images horizontally in the view.

App crashes in the following line:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked Image Button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Implementation:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
        final int position = pos;  

        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
        viewHolder.imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);

        viewHolder.imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Crashes in the following line
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked Image Button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((FrameLayout) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: it does not show anything in the logcat. it just crashes

Comment: First it is not possible that not showing log.
your all other paramater are correct .

Comment: When I comment out Toast.makeText, it does not crashes. I could not able to see any errors in the logcat. app just crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saying no logcat showing for **ERROR** I am only assuming that your **context is null**.

try this solution

```
if(context != null)
    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked Image Button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else
    Log.d("You Clicked Image Button", "Position : " + position);
```

Comment: Any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377100/recyclerview-item-position-does-not-get-update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code, Hope it works

```
Toast.makeText(context,"item Clicked at "+getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```