# RecyclerView Item position does not get update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In the following code, I could able to delete the image via clicking imgBtn, but my images does not scroll the deleted image position, it just stays its current position, it does not update.

**Main Activity Class**

```
ItemData itemsData[] = {new ItemData("Help", R.drawable.image),
            new ItemData("Delete", R.drawable.orange),
            new ItemData("Cloud", R.drawable.image),
            new ItemData("Favorite", R.drawable.orange),
            new ItemData("Like", R.drawable.image),
            new ItemData("Rating", R.drawable.orange)};

 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
 llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
 CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(itemsData);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**ItemData Class**

```
public class ItemData {
private String title;
private int imageUrl;

public ItemData(String title,int imageUrl){

    this.title = title;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
String getTitle(){return title;}
void setTitle(String t){title = t;}
int getImageUrl(){return imageUrl;}
void setImageUrl(int t){imageUrl = t;}
}
```

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private ItemData[] itemsData;
    private Context context;
    private CustomAdapter thisAdapter = this;

    public CustomAdapter( ItemData[] itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
    final int position = pos;  

    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    viewHolder.imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);

    viewHolder.imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((FrameLayout) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();
        }
    });
 }

}
```

Comment: do you want to delete image from that position

Comment: I could able to the selected image from that position `((FrameLayout) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();`, but the other images positions does not get update. Deleted image position stays empty with no image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove Item from the recylerview. dont do it like this.

Because you using ItemData[] array

```
List<ItemData> numlist = new ArrayList<ItemData>();
for(int i= 0;i<itemsData.length;i++)
{
    if(i == position)
    {
        // No operation here 
    }
    else
    {
        numlist.add(arr_fav[i]);
    }
}
itemsData = numlist.toArray(new String[numlist .size()]);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mDataset.size());
```

If you convert it to `List<ItemData>` Go with [asadmshas's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35377174/2900893)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid manually modifying the views when using a RecyclerView. Use the adapters notify* methods to push any updates to the list view. In your specific case I'd suggest using a `List<ItemData>` instead of an array and then in your `onClickListener` code I'd do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    itemsData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

I can't exactly tell how the data is used to populate your RecyclerView, I'm assuming it is itemsData, but you'd remove the item in question from it and then issue a `notifyItemRemoved(position)` call to that adapter.